# View Facebook Live in iOS App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I think I understand that the API allows for broadcasting to Facebook live from app, but is it possible to listen for a particular user and VIEW the live video within an app?  I've never seen an example of an app doing this, but was just curious if it is possible to do so.

Comment: I was looking for the same info, answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42769590/535915

Comment: Doesn't look like a good solution if no more than 10 viewers @Mudar

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear: it's not possible to view stream within your own app. The API does provide a video URL, but it's for preview purposes only.