# Can I use "dash_preview_url(in Facebook Live API)" for live streaming to my app's users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I'm making a Facebook Live app.
So.. I want to stream Facebook Live via my app.
And I found this api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/#Reading).

As you can see, Live Read API has "dash_preview_url".
So.. This is my question.
"Can I use "dash_preview_url(in Facebook Live API)" for live streaming to my app's users. (Not for broadcasters, for viewers.)"
"When I use this, is it against Facebook's Terms of Service?"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `dash_preview_url`, but `preview_url` is not intended for a player's stream:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/production-broadcasts

> After creating a live video in preview, you can query the live video node for the preview_url. This url can be used in a 3rd party RTMP player to verify video and audio content (see example below).
>
> It's important to note that the preview_url can only be used for 4 hours and is limited to no more than 10 viewers.